# How do I dump the configuration of a jersey web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, jersey

When things go wrong with a jersey web application, you hit endpoints that you believe exist, and those endpoints return 404 Not Found.

The code 404 Not Found means that what one believes is so, and what is actually so, do not match.

Does a mechanism exist in jersey to dump the effective configuration during startup, so that jersey tells us what it's configuration is, as opposed to us guessing wrong and being constantly told "that's not it, guess again"?